# mapping a new domain name to existing IP

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a java application hosted in aws as an ec2 instance with a hosted zone and record sets for NS and SOA and it works fine.

I access the application using a url which looks like https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/----

I have a registered domain name and I want to map the domain name to the above address. I tried creating A record but the name is not being resolved. It gives me the error 'Server not Found'.

How do I assign my domain name to point to my existing IP.?

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See *[How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632)* for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to create a DNS A record.

Comment: I tried doing that but my IP is 52.76.222.138:8443. It does'nt accept the port along with the IP

Comment: That's correct, the DNS knows nothing about and does not care about ports.

Comment: @KunalK Before you go any further, do yourself and the internet a good deed: read this http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPDomainNameSystemDNS.htm